# d3 indented tree to ms word using phpword

Tags: javascript, xml, d3.js, ms-word, phpword

[This indented tree](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1093025) is a good reference for what I'm trying to do.

I want an indented tree to be inserted in MicroSoft word. I am thinking of using a textbox in phpword as a rectangle in a d3 tree.

The d3 has xml data. If I loop through the xml data to get its content then I think this could be done. Here's the xml:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1100" height="650" style="background-color: rgb(247, 247, 247);">
 <g transform="translate(20,30)">
<path class="link" d="M0,0C10,0 10,23 20,23" style="fill: none; stroke: rgb(158, 202, 225); stroke-width: 1.5px;"/>
<g class="node" transform="translate(0,0)">
    <rect y="-10" height="20" width="968" style="fill: rgb(223, 233, 243);"/>
    <text x="0" dy="3.5" dx="5.5" style="font-size: 10px;">PBFT SPC OCAP</text>
    <text class="redirect_link" dy="3.5" dx="5.5" x="888" style="font-size: 10px; text-decoration: underline; font-weight: bold;"/>
</g>
<g class="node" transform="translate(20,23)">
    <rect y="-10" height="20" width="948" style="fill: rgb(148, 189, 218);"/>
    <text x="0" dy="3.5" dx="5.5" style="font-size: 10px;">Perform SPC Data Monitoring using SPC system based control chart</text>
    <text class="redirect_link" dy="3.5" dx="5.5" x="868" style="font-size: 10px; text-decoration: underline; font-weight: bold;"/>
</g>
```

Here's the phpword code:

```
 $phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();

 $section = $phpWord->addSection();

// In section
$textbox = $section->addTextBox(
array(
    'align'       => 'center',
    'width'       => 400,
    'height'      => 150,
    'borderSize'  => 1,
    'borderColor' => '#FF0000',
)
);

  $textbox->addText(htmlspecialchars('Text box content in section.'));
```

Using that xml data above how can I loop through that data and insert the data to phpword?

Comment: PHP runs on the server while D3 runs in the browser. You would need to send what D3 produces back to the server.